# enum parameter wont return values from database

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, enums

i have some data in my project that are calling for ENUM so I decided to implement it. The problem is i´m not getting data back from the database. There must be some configuration I'm missing and i can't figure it out. Here are some code samples

**Repository:**

```
 @Query(value="SELECT student_account_table.* FROM student_account student_account_table INNER JOIN student student_table ON student_account_table.student_account_id = studdent_table.student.id WHERE student_table.grade= :studentGrade", nativeQuery=true)
 List<StudentAccount> getStudentAccounts(@Param("studentGrade") StudentGrades studentGrade);
```

**StudentAccounImplementation:**

```
@Override
    public List<StudentAccount> getStudentAccounts(StudentGrades studentGrade) {
        return studentAccountRepository.getStudentAccounts(studentGrade);
    }
```

**Calling the method:**

```
    public void eraseStudent(){
            List<StudentAccount> eraseThis= studentAccountImplementation.getStudentAccounts(StudentGrades.E);    

 //This method doesn't work because the list is empty        
            studentAccountImplementation.eraseStudents(eraseThis);
        }
```

**Enum:**

```
public enum StudentGrades{
    A, B, C, D, E;
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Column(name = "student_grade")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StudentGrades studentGrade;
```

Constructor and other code missing for brevity.
I have tried every possible solution found here at SO and the mighty Google with no success. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by converting the Enum values to a string. That was it.

**The Fix:**

```
 public void eraseStudent(){
            List<StudentAccount> eraseThis= studentAccountImplementation.getStudentAccounts(StudentGrades.E.toString());    

 //This method doesn't work because the list is empty        
            studentAccountImplementation.eraseStudents(eraseThis);
        }
```

I hope the answer helps someone.